# How to specify header values in Meteor.http.post call?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I specify `Content Type` in Meteor server API call. Below is my API call

```
var result = Meteor.http.post(URL, {
      params: {
        summaryLength: "500",
        entryPoint: "main"
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
```

This call nor returns the proper JSON response. Please provide a proper way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``Content-Type`` is for telling the service what you are sending. Specify ``Accept`` (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header, which is meant to tell what content type you expect in the response. So add ``'Accept': 'application/json'`` to the headers. IF the service is implemented properly and supports JSON, it should send JSON back.

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading the documentation, that **is** how you set the headers. That said, `params` doesn't encode the data as JSON so that header is a lie.

Comment: @Quentin - you are right. IF he wants to send JSON, he has to use ``data`` options instead - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call.

Comment: use `HTTP.call` not `Meteor.http` not sure if makes a difference but It's first time I see `Meteor.http` being used

Comment: @Quentin & tiblue: Thanks for your responses. Changing params to data worked and returned proper response.

Answer (score 0):

For others, I am posting the answer based on the comments from @Quintin and @tiblue.

```
var result = Meteor.http.post(URL, {
      data: {
        summaryLength: "500",
        entryPoint: "main"
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will help you.

```
var url = "your url";
var options = {
    'headers':{ 'Authorization': 'Bearer 0c724a3b-fg25-f4b0-afe9-q76b74533e21',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
}; 
HTTP.call('GET', url, options, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
        console.log("error",error);
        //cb && cb(new Meteor.Error(500, 'There was an error processing your request.', error));
  } else {
         console.log("result",result);
         cb && cb(null, result);
  }
});
```